# Sending messages to groups using SignalR Core

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

This is my first implementation of `SignalR` and I'm starting with `SignalR Core` so some of the examples and documentation don't seem to apply to the new version.

My objective is to send the received message to a particular chat room. I understand this could be achieved using `Groups`.

First question: I'm not seeing a way to check if a connection is already in a group. Do I NOT need to check if a connection is already in the `Group`? I receive a `ChatRoomId` with each message so I can easily add the user/connection to a `Group`. I just want to know if I need to check whether or not the connection is already a member of group.

Second question: I want to exclude the sender from receiving the broadcast of his own message. Looks like `OthersInGroup` has been removed from `SignalR Core`. How do I exclude the sender if I'm sending the message to a `Group`?

These are the options I'm getting from IntelliSense:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first question:**

There is no built in way to check if a connection is in a group. It is up to you to handle that via an injected service to your hub or a static Dictionary or something. So each time you call `Groups.AddAsync` and `Groups.RemoveAsync` you can keep track of that.

**For the second question:**

`GroupExcept(string groupName, IReadOnlyList<string> excludeIds)` was added recently and should be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I installed the latest alpha through NuGet and I'm not getting the GroupExcept. You said it was added recently so maybe it hasn't made it into NuGet yet?

Comment: Posted to the original post a screen shot of the options IntelliSense gives me.

Answer (score 2):

**For the second question:**
GroupExcept method is not available on SignalR alpha. 
You need the preview. 
You can add it running on the PM: 
dotnet add PROJECTNAME package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR --version 2.1.0-preview1-27884 --source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json

Comment: Thank you. What about client side scripts? Do I need to update them as well?

Comment: With a C# client I had to update the dlls, but I can't tell about js